# Mail: Forward e-mails and also keep a copy

Tags: email

I am using the `~/.forward` file to forward my institution's e-mails to my Gmail account. I also want a copy of e-mails to be kept in the institution servers. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/584866/edit) your question to include some more information about your setup, in particular OS flavor and version, and the mail transport agent installed.

Answer (score 0):

You have only your gmail address in your `.forward` file, right?. You can add another e-mail or local account name to your `.forward` file. Can you have another account on your institution server, where you can forward the messages to? For instance:

```
mail.address@gmail.com
another_local_account
```

In that way, you forward to local and to gmail mailboxes. So you have mail locally and in your GMail account.

You can also specify a filename in your `.forward` file like this `/home/account/mail_duplicates`, and mails will be added to that file. I am not sure if that is already in mbox format.

You can redirect mails to a program that can process them `|~/my_mail_duplicater`. In that cas you can write a program, that would save mails somewhere or even put them in local mailbox.